# Force text to move up if it goes outside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div "container" and a p holding some text. The text inside of the p is taken from a input textbox. So the length of the text may vary. 
I always want the text to be inside of the div. And I do not want the div length to adjust after the text length.
Instead if the text is about to go outside the div I want the text to be moved up.
Is that possible? And if so, then how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set `overflow: scroll;` to `#container`.

Comment: Well, that works. However in my case the entire content is ment to be printed. And you cant scroll on a paper :P. So that does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The div style should include "overflow:none".  Once you fill the paragraph element, use script to set the offsetTop of the paragraph element to the offsetHeight of the element less the scrollHeight of the div.